# Customizing nopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net, nopcommerce

We are developing an nopCommerce based application. Our login page needs to be minimalistic and would need only an email id, password entry fields and a Login button.

Could you point me to best practices for achieving the above objective ?

Do I modify the corresponding pages found in \Presentation\Nop.Web\Views\Customer\ & controllers in \Presentation\Nop.Web\Controllers\

Or

Is there a better way of doing this and organizing all the modified files in one place/folder so that upgrading to future versions of nopCommerce will not be difficult ?

The requirement is to ensure that all the changes made to the project(views/controllers etc) are in one folder so that they are not overwritten when we upgrade to a newer version of nopCommerce.

I read somewhere that you can copy stuff you need to change (Login.chtml, CustomerController) to Themes/DefaultClean and then make your changes in this folder. I dont remember where i read it.

I feel doing so will make it that much easier to maintain our codebase because all your custom code is in one place/folder/sub folders

Is this a best practise? And is there a disadvantage to this method of doing things?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to modify your nopCommerce project without changing anything in the core code would be to use the plugin functionality which is described [here](https://docs.nopcommerce.com/en/developer/plugins/how-to-write-plugin-4.40.html) (assuming you're using the newest version 4.40).

To change the login page you would then need to create your modified version as a .cshtml file in your plugin. You then need to set this file as Content and set the *Copy to Output Directory* property to Copy if Newer or Copy Always.

You also need to implement the *IViewLocationExpander* interface so that the Razor Engine knows that it should use your custom Login Page. The implementation should look something like this:

```
public class MyViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
   public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
   {
      if(context.ViewName == "Login")
      {
         viewLocations = new[] { "PathToCustomLoginPage" }.Concat(viewLocations);
      }

      return viewLocations;
   }

   public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
   {
      return;
   }
}
```

After that you also need to register your ViewExpander by implementing the *INopStartup* interface. The implementation would look something like this:

```
public class MyStartup : INopStartup
{
   public int Order => int.MaxValue;

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
   {
   }

   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
   {
      services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
      {
         options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new MyViewLocationExpander());
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank we so very much for your detailed post. I will modify the Login page as you have suggested and see if that it solves my problem. Thank you once again!